# Allow all users to call sudo -l

Tags: debian, sudo

On my debian server, when a user who does not have any rights in the sudoers file or any include dirs, calls `sudo -l`, he gets the standard "responsibility header" and is prompted for his password.

Is it possible to allow all users on a system to call the `sudo -l` command without needing to specify their password? Preferably, if the user has no privileges, it should just report that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `sudo -l` to the allowed commands for all users. Edit the sudoers file with `visudo` and add a line like this:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -l
```

When a user now calls `sudo -l` the output looks as follows:

```
User foo may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -l
```

Unfortunately the user has not no privileges anymore, because he can invoke `sudo -l`, so the output of `sudo -l` is not `Sorry, user foo may not run sudo on host` anymore.

Comment: For people finding this by web searching, sudo now has an option in `sudoers` to support specifically this situation:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574576/how-to-enable-password-less-listing-of-sudo-permissions-sudo-l-without-addi