# sudo -l when runas_default is a different user

Tags: sudo

For reasons, in order to utilize system administration commands, it is necessary to use a two-factored account. This account is different than the normal login account. For example, if the standard login account is "alice", then the two-factored account might be "alice2".

I have a `sudo` file (one per allowed user, in /etc/sudoers.d) that is similar to the following:

```
Defaults:alice  runaspw,runas_default=alice2

alice ALL=(alice2) /bin/bash
```

This works in that "alice" is prompted for the password for "alice2" (which is a two-factor only password), and then "alice" is changed to the "alice2" account. From there, I have a separate `sudo` file that allows alice2 to use any `sudo` command without a password.

So all appears to be fine as far as the two-factor authentication goes. However, there are a few commands that are exempt from this two-factor approach (such as restarting some services on certain machines). I also have that working, I think, by lines such as

```
Cmnd_Alias  SRVCHTTPD = /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd
Defaults!SRVCHTTPD  !runaspw,runas_default=root
```

Here, the user "alice" is prompted for the password for "alice", and the service may be restarted.

Now my issue. When a user does `sudo -l` to see what commands may be executed, the user is prompted for the two-factor account (alice2) rather than the main account (alice). I tried adding a command alias ([following a suggestion here on sudo -l](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163553/allow-all-users-to-call-sudo-l)), essentially replicating the lines above.

```
Cmnd_Alias SUDOLIST = /usr/bin/sudo -l
Defaults!SUDOLIST !runaspw,runas_default=root
```

However, this approach did not work, and the user was still prompted for the two-factor account password.

I'd appreciate any advice on what I'm not doing correctly here.

Comment: I'm not sure how `sudo` arbitrates in this case, though the man page says *the last match is used* in some circumstances. You could try adding the SUDOLIST defaults line after the line starting `alice` to see if it changes things.

Comment: @meuh, Thank you for the suggestion! I tried moving a few things around (location of the SUDOLIST in the alice file; position of the `Defaults!SUDOLIST`), but unfortunately no joy.  Interestingly, I changed `/etc/sudoers.d/alice` to be `alice ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SUDOLIST` and that **did** work (allowed `sudo -l` without a password). But this latter approach isn't quite right. I believe you are correct it is something about the arbitration order, just don't know how to fix it.